# Elastic Beanstalk run post deploy script

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My node.js app consists of two things, an express backend and a react frontend.

I have two package.json files in this structure

```
package.json 
/app/package.json
```

What I want to do is run a script in my frontend folder, app, that builds my code.

the script I want to run is `npm install` and `npm run build`
How do I run this script after a deploy have happened?

```
commands:
    01_app_npm_install:
        command: npm install
        cwd: app/
    02_app_npm_build:
        command: npm run build
        cwd: app/
```

But it returns an error saying that "No such file or direc
tory: 'app/'."

Is this possible to do on aws elastic beanstalk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @gustaf and some other sites I managed to pull a solution together. It's not pretty but it works.

I created a file in `.ebextensions/01_build.config`

```
commands:
  create_post_dir:
    command: "mkdir /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post"
    ignoreErrors: true
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_build_app.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      cd /var/app/current/app/
      sudo /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.2.2-linux-x64/bin/npm install
      sudo /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.2.2-linux-x64/bin/npm run build
```

hard coding the node-version is not perfect but it works for now.

Comment: I don't think you need to create that directory, it should be there already. I didn't have to do that in a python environment. You could obviously move a file into that directory in container_commands as well if you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. One question, I used your answer but cannot figure out how can I set env variables when building react app. It is undefined even though I set it in GUI configuration. Have you encounter the same issue?

Answer (score 14):

Update:
This is now much more developed and defined.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html

Original:

I haven't done nodejs myself with Elastic Beanstalk, but I have done a lot of Django.

The `commands:` section runs before the project files are put in place. This is where you can install server packages for example.

The `container_commands:` section runs in a staging directory before the files are put in its final destination (which is /var/app/current it seems for nodejs). Here you can modify your files if you need to.

Reference for above:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html

You can also run a post deploy scripts. This is not very well documented (at least it wasn't). You can do something like this:

```
files:
    "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_restart_delayed_job.sh":
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            #!/usr/bin/env bash
            service httpd restart
```

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction, BUT, as of AWS Linux 2, this is slightly different, see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html

You must create a folder called .platform/hooks and put content like

#!/usr/bin/env bash
service httpd restart

Right into the file

Answer (score 2):

If you refer to the docs you'll find that `container_commands` is where you should put the app related stuff.

The file is executed based on preference of various parts, `commands` being the first and `container_commands` being the last. During this phase, the app hasn't been copied to the desired location (`/var/app/current`).

Also, if you set environment variables, these will be available to you in `container_commands` only.

Comment: Even if I change it to container_commands it still can't find the directory app/.

I have the .config file in a directory called .ebextensions, is that correct?

Comment: Its not working for me too. Throwing below err in eb-engine.log
2022/03/01 16:08:00.766820 [INFO] Following scripts will be executed in order: [99post_deploy_script.sh]
2022/03/01 16:08:00.766826 [INFO] Running script: .platform/hooks/postdeploy/99post_deploy_script.sh
2022/03/01 16:08:00.770608 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [RunAppDeployPostDeployHooks]. Stop running the command. Error: Command .platform/hooks/postdeploy/99post_deploy_script.sh failed with error exit status 127. Stde: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

As of Amazon Linux 2 you must use [Platform Hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html). Other answers here only work with Amazon Linux AMI platform versions.

For example in your application root, create the

> .platform/hooks/postdeploy

folder(s), then create a file called service-httpd-restart.sh

with contents of

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
service httpd restart
```

To do the same thing as [Gustaf's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40777656/1165619).